# How to get images displayed asynchrnously in Django, Python?

Tags: python, django, image, asynchronous

I am trying to find a way in which I can generate the images in the background and display the images in front end as they are getting generated asynchronously without waiting for the image generation to complete as its creating a huge number of images and I dont want the browser to wait till the time all the images are generated. Can you please tell me how to do it in the frontend as well as backend? And what is the correct way to do it?

The images are labeled 0.png, 1.png. Every time the number of images generated varies. I dont know initially the number of images that will be generated. The images are saved in the static folder. Right now I have in my index.html template.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
   {% for plot in plots%}
      {% with plot|add:".png" as image_static %}
          <ul class="myList"><li><img src="{% static image_static %}" alt="My image"/></li></ul>
      {% endwith %}
   {% endfor %}
```

My views.py looks like below

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    count=Genplots.main() # main function to generate images
    p=list(range(count)) #number of images
    p=map(str,p)
    return render_to_response("plots/index.html", { 'plots':p})
```

The problem is this waits for all the images to begenerated before displaying them in the frontend. Please help.

Comment: display only placeholders then after dom ready send ajax request for several generated thumbnails and url to full size image ...

Comment: Hi @madzohan, will it automatically update once the image is generated. Can you please clarify? Also how would I know the number of images?

Comment: @sachinsrivastava, could you post `Genplots.main()`?

Comment: Hi @twil, Thank you for your reply. I actually cannot since its proprietary. But it basically is a script which creates plots in a loop and saves it in a folder. In this case a static folder(Im not sure if this is correct place). So, it will create a plot save it as .png and then create another and so on.

Comment: Ok, being in your shoes I'd use something like Celery to create a background task to generate these plots (run the task inside `Genplots.main()`). Then I'd return a number of plots from `Genplots.main()`. Then - like @madzohan said - create placeholders in the front-end and some JS magic to periodically load (test) images. And of cource I'd use media and not static folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  These templates are rendered on the server, so by the time your browser receives the HTML, it already has orders to load the image.

You need to accomplish this with JavaScript - something like [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)